# Convert a varchar(10) into an int in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Is it possible to convert a `varchar(10)` into an `int` in SQL Server 2014?

I tried the following code, but I get a conversion error

```
Declare @Random varchar(10)
set @Random = CONVERT(varchar, right(newid(),10))
Declare @rand int = cast(@Random as int)
select @rand
```

Comment: `RIGHT(NEWID(), 10)` is only an integer by supreme coincidence. You *could* convert the hexstring to an integer, but at this point you're better off explaining why you'd want it, because there's almost certainly a better solution for whatever problem that's intended to solve (like `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM`).

Comment: but `newid()` gives you a guid with alpha numerics, why would that convert to an int? add this line to your code before you attempt to cast to int: `SELECT @Random` and see what you're trying to convert.

Comment: `NEWID` generate a characters, not only numbers.

Comment: i'm trying to generate a random varchar(10) and converting it into an int, the Select @Random prints something like: '9B5B89F3'

Comment: Can you convert 'ABC' to INT?

Comment: This is a classic XY problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Title says SQL Server **2014**, body says **2012** - which one is it now?

Comment: @Tanner I wanted at first to generate a random 10 digit number. How can I do that without going through the newid() that generates letters as well as you said ?

Comment: tell us why you need a random number and you'll get a better answer

Comment: An `INT` will not contain 10 random digits; the biggest integer is 2147483647. You'd need a `BIGINT` to hold 10 arbitrary digits. `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM()` is a better way to get random bits than extracting them from a GUID (`CONVERT(INT, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4))`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to convert a varchar(10) into an int under SQL Server 2012?

Yes, if the `varchar(10)` string is all numeric characters and the string is within the bound of an `int`:

```
-2^31 (-2,147,483,648) to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647)
```

In other words, this will work:

```
select cast('2147483647' as int)
```

This will not:

```
select cast('2147483648' as int)
```

> I tried the following code, but I get a conversion error

The code in your question isn't testing whether you *can* convert a string to an integer, it is testing whether *any random string* can be converted. Your random strings contain alpha characters that cannot convert to an integer so you are getting conversion errors.  But even if you limit the random string to numbers, you will still only be able to convert numeric strings up to `2147483647` before you overflow your `int`.  I don't think that generating (not-so) random strings that meet this criteria will prove much.  The simple answer to your question is yes, you can convert a string to an int, as long as the string meets the requirements of an int.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
SELECT TRY_CAST(RIGHT(CAST(convert(VARBINARY, NEWID(), 1) AS BIGINT),10) AS INT);
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/MPNY64512)**

Or if you use only 9 digitis:

```
SELECT RIGHT(CAST(convert(VARBINARY, NEWID(), 1) AS BIGINT),9) + 0;
```